# Inheriting css class which is located in another file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am using bootstrap and less.

I want one of my class to inherit from a bootstrap class. The problem is I am using bootstrap from a cdn and don't want to have any bootsrap file locally.

Is it possible to import a css class from a cdn file using less or inherit a class which is not in the file ?

Comment: Yes, Less `@import` works with non-local files just fine: [codepen](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/JmBLt)
(Assuming you understand the difference between importing Bootstrap Less sources and Bootstrap CSS files).

Comment: But regardless of above it still looks like a strange wish (Less will have to download this file each time you compile), so depending on what exactly you're trying to do there may be better ways.

Comment: @seven-phases-max The ideal way would be to use the bootstrap class already downloaded from the cdn. The problem is that we can't access class from another file. I can't reference the bootstrap class .form-control within my main.css file.

Comment: In the codepen I linked above this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been answered by seven-phases-max.

Less support import of file by url. You just have to tagg it as a less file, like this :

```
@import (less) "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css";
```

[Example here](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/JmBLt). Then you can reference to the class imported via url.

It is working, but inheriting a bootstrap class does not import all of the class feature. I inherited all my input with the class .form-control. Some of the features of the bootstrap form-control where imported (size, rounded corner) and others don't (blue light when selected). More about this [here](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/cefc873a78fa12924462).

```
input[type="text"]{
    .form-control;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to install anything. Just download the less file you want to use [from GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/less) and import it:

```
@import (reference) "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/less/buttons.less";
```

[Less Import](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options)

But I don’t think that's a good idea anyway. Less will have to request that file every time you compile.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to have any bootstrap file locally. I want to dowload all of them from a cdn (I edited my post to state it clearly).

Comment: @Moebius You should be able to directly speciify the url. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working, the ajax request generate an error : Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/less/forms.less. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: @Moebius So are you compiling the less in the browser? Is this really necessary? You can also try the general bootstrap.css file from max cdn.

Comment: Downloading bootstrap from maxcdn is not generating any error, bootstrap is just not loaded at all.