# Accessing css class from another file

Tags: css, less

I have a css class and I want it to inherit from another class (using less). The problem is that the class I want to inherit from is not in the same file.

Since the class I want to get access to is downloaded from a cdn, I can't import this css file in my file.

Is it possible to have access to a class without importing the file containing it ?

Comment: @ElGavilan That's what I want to avoid.

Comment: Avoid Import and Copy/Paste? Then, most probably the only answer would be NO.

Comment: What do you mean by "accessing css class"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been answered by seven-phases-max.

Less support import of file by url. You just have to tagg it as a less file, like this :

```
@import (less) "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Then you can reference to the class imported via url.

It is working, but inheriting a bootstrap class does not import all of the class feature. I inherited all my input with the class .form-control. Some of the features of the bootstrap form-control where imported (size, rounded corner) and others don't (blue light when selected). More about this [here](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/cefc873a78fa12924462).

```
input[type="text"]{
    .form-control;
    width: 50%;
}
```

This is a copy of my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888927/inheriting-css-class-which-is-located-in-another-file/25907375#25907375).

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to reference to that file at least some time in the process. It's impossible to get something from a file, without referencing to it. 
The only way to do this with CSS is, as far as I know, [@import](http://www.cssnewbie.com/css-import-rule/). (from within a CSS-file) Yes, you will be importing the complete file.

Or use the `<link>`-tag in the page where you have to use that particular CSS, so it doesn't get loaded in on every page.

No matter which way you reference to the external CSS-file, it's a bad idea as the file can be (re)moved or changed. Better is to just copy/paste from the original file (as mentioned in the comments on your question) or save a version of the css-file on your server